# What headers does App Engine Flex forward to your application?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

It's not very well documented anywhere. Specifically, if I want to detect http vs https, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, with some names/IP addresses changed. You can use `X-Forwarded-Proto` to detect http vs https in App Engine Flex.

```
"X-Appengine-Region": "ca",
"X-Cloud-Trace-Context": "8b8613a90a389a6c1e125b330ab20b24/6635756377403605329",
"X-Appengine-Country": "US",
"X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
"X-Appengine-Citylatlong": "23.774929,-120.419416",
"X-Appengine-City": "city name",
"Via": "1.1 google",
"X-Forwarded-For": "1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do these public docs meet your needs? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled